# Wrong format conversion from SQL query

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a strange problem when I go to filter with a query the column `DATE_INSERT` (of type `DATETIME`).

I tried these two queries:

Query #1:

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(DATE_INSERT, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss') as DATA_INSERIMENTO, 
    COD_ART_PF, DESCR_PF, LOTTO_PF, COD_MP, DESCR_MP, LOTTO_MP, QTA_MP, 
    CAPO_TURNO 
FROM
    ZZ_ANABASIPRODUCO_MP 
WHERE
    LOTTO_MP = '0' 
    AND QTA_MP <> '0' 
    AND DATA_INSERIMENTO BETWEEN '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "' 
ORDER BY
    LOTTO_PF
```

Query #2:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        FORMAT(DATE_INSERT, 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss') AS DATA_INSERIMENTO, 
        COD_ART_PF, DESCR_PF, LOTTO_PF, COD_MP, DESCR_MP, LOTTO_MP, QTA_MP, 
        CAPO_TURNO
    FROM 
        ZZ_ANABASIPRODUCO_MP
)
SELECT
    DATA_INSERIMENTO, DATA_INSERIMENTO, COD_ART_PF, DESCR_PF, LOTTO_PF, 
    COD_MP, DESCR_MP, LOTTO_MP, QTA_MP, CAPO_TURNO
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE 
    LOTTO_MP = '0' 
    AND QTA_MP <> '0' 
    AND DATA_INSERIMENTO BETWEEN '01/07/2019 00:00:00' AND '03/07/2019 23:59:59'
```

But the results are always wrong, it's like reversing the day and the month even if you format them correctly

This is the results of both queries:

```
| DATA_INSERIMENTO | LOTTO_PF      |
+------------------+---------------+
| 03/01/2019       | 040585190701B |
| 03/01/2019       | 060428190701B |
| 02/02/2019       | 040585190701B |
| 02/02/2019       | 040585190701C |
| 02/02/2019       | 040585190701C |
| 02/02/2019       | 060528190701C |
| 02/02/2019       | 030330190702A |
```

The results are many and I can't put them all but I can tell you that the months go from 01 to 07 and the days from 01 to 03 as in the table.

Comment: How do you know the day and month are switched? How do you know whether `03/01/2019` is in January or March?

Comment: Given that your format includes time, but your result does not, it's unclear if your client code is re-parsing the data, you made a mistake, or something else. Also, your `BETWEEN` is operating on a textual field rather than a `DATETIME`, which is obviously wrong even if the text came out correct. *Also* also, your code is using textual replacement instead of parameters, which is a terrible idea -- aside from SQL injection, you leave yourself open to date formatting issues just like these. Use typed `SqlParameter`s and avoid `FORMAT` altogether. Leave formatting to the client.

Comment: @honeybadger right, but on the complete table the first position goes from 01 to 03, while the second goes from 01 to 07.
I filter from 01/07 to 03/07, and the results progressively go from:
01/01 -> 03/01
01/02 -> 03/02
01/03 -> 03/03
01/04 -> 03/04
01/05 -> 03/05
01/06 -> 03/06
01/07 -> 03/07

Comment: @Jeroen  yeah, the time on the table is present, during the paste he just pasted  the date.
I have also tried to remove the FORMAT but the result does not change. do you suggest then to convert it to string?

Comment: On the client side, yes. As written your `BETWEEN` cannot operate correctly because it compares strings which are not in chronological order. `02/11/2019` is also `BETWEEN '01/07/2019' and '03/07/2019'` (because `'1' < '2' < '3'`), yet obviously not what you want. Get `DATETIME`s as `DATETIME`s and not as strings, and compare them to typed parameter values, not strings. The client side can then do `.ToString()` using whatever format it prefers.

Comment: Use  ANSI datetime format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss` or explicitly specify the style in `CONVERT` function when you are trying to get a datetime value from a string.

Comment: Last but not least, when comparing dates you generally want to avoid `BETWEEN` and use `>=` and `<`. As written, even if it worked (which it doesn't for reasons described above) your query would exclude any times between 23:59:59 and 00:00:00 (leaving out a second of data). An exclusive upper bound does not have this problem.